# Flutter - Barcode Scanner and ListView

Tags: flutter, barcode, barcode-scanner, flutter-listview

I have implemented **Barcode Scanning** in Flutter.

**Dependency:**

```
  barcode_scan: any
```

**Code:**

```
  Future _scanBarcode(BuildContext context) async {
    try {
      ScanResult scanResult = await BarcodeScanner.scan(options: ScanOptions(

      ));
      String query = scanResult.rawContent;
      print("Scanned Value : $query");
    } on PlatformException catch (e) {
      if (e.code == BarcodeScanner.cameraAccessDenied) {
        _showErrorSnackbar(context, 'The user did not grant the camera permission!');
      } else {
        _showErrorSnackbar(context, 'Unknown error: $e');
      }
    } catch (e) {
      _showErrorSnackbar(context, 'Unknown error: $e');
    }
  }
```

I want to open a barcode scanner inside the activity with ListView (in 50% of the screen)

How to keep a barcode scanner in half of the screen.

I want to scan infinitely and display details in another half of the screen (Bind each scanned item in ListView.)

Can anyone give hint? Help me?

Answer (score 1):

I have done it using **[scan_preview](https://pub.dev/packages/scan_preview/example)** package.

What I have done is:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Barcode Scanner"),
          centerTitle: true,
        ),
        body: Column(
          children: [
            SizedBox(
              width: double.infinity,
              height: height/1.5,
              child: ScanPreviewWidget(
                onScanResult: (result) {
                  debugPrint('scan result: $result');
                  setState(() {
                    barcode = result;
                  });
                },
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 20),
            Center(child: Text(barcode))
          ],
        ));
  }
```

[image]